# How to get last child in the self referencing table hierarchy?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table like:

```
public class Cycle     
{
    public Guid Id 
    public int CycleNo 
    public Cycle ParentCycle 
}
```

Which have data as:

```
Id  CycleNo  ParentId  
C1  1         null  
C2  2         C1  
C3  3         C2
```

And so on....
If I have c1, how to get last child C3 (in this case)?
Thanks for your  valuable input..

Answer (score 1):

Get the full tree for your node :

```
session.CreateQuery(
    "select c from Cycle c join fetch c.ParentCycle where c.Id = 'C1'"
)
.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
.List<Cycle>();
```

(or an equivalent using Query, or CreateCriteria)

See : http://ayende.com/blog/4151/nhibernate-tips-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree

Then traverse it in memory.